# mongoose, timestamps not created when pushing

Tags: express, mongoose

I'am making a movie app where the users can post a comment for each movie. All the movie is placed on a single document, here is the schema:

```
const movieInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: {
        type: [movieSchema],
        default: []
    },

    title: {
        type: String,
        default: "movieInfos"
    }
})
```

for each movie has schema:

```
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },

    comments: {
        type: [commentSchema]
    },

    likedBy: [likeBySchema]

}, { _id: false });
```

Each movie has comments that the user can post, and I add a schema too.

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
    },

}, {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }
})
```

Now, when i'am posting comments it works and it stores in the database but the timestamps is not created for each comment.

Here's how i put comments in the comments array.

```
router.post("/postComment/:id", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const { comment } = req.body;

        const newQuery = {
            $push: {
                'data.$.comments': {
                    username:req.user.username,
                    comment: comment
                }
            },
        }

        const movie = await movieModel.findOneAndUpdate({ title: "movieInfos", 'data.id': id }, newQuery, {upsert:true, new: true, runValidators: true, timeStamps: true});
        
        console.log(movie);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message + " comment error  ")
    }
});
```

The output of this in the database when I execute it is:

```
{
    username: "name",
    comments: "comment"
}
```

but my expected output should be

```
{
    username: "name",
    comments: "comment",
    created_at: date, // Date when created
    updated_at: date //  Date when updated
}
```

Comment: I believe this is an issue when you try to set timestamps on a subdoc of a subdoc (child element of a child element). Timestamps will work well one layer deep without any problems but when you go two deep it is a good indication you may need to revisit your data modelling designs.